# VScode Code custom task: "terminal process terminated with exit code: 1."

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have configured my first custom task in Visual Studio code as follows to run [bun.js](https://bun.sh/) (a javascript runtime alternative to Node.js or Deno):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "my task",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "bun",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "dev"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "new",
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run the task I get the following error message:

`The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -e bun run main.ts" terminated with exit code: 1.`

I am running Ubuntu Linux on a windows machine and I have verified that the wsl executable is in the above path.

What is causing this process to fail?

Comment: have you looked at all the available variables, there is one you want

Comment: I've been trying to find a configuration that allows me to do it. I think I have tried all of them but can find it. Do you know which one it is @rioV8?

Comment: How many have you tried? How many are there?

Comment: Well, there are 15 parameters as far as I can see. The only thing I can think of that might control it is `supressTaskName` or possibly changing the working directory or somehow changing the current working directory under `runOptions`. Am I on the right track @rioV8?

Comment: I talk about `variables` not parameters of the launch

Comment: Oh, I see. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Let me give it a try.

Comment: I have now changed args to: `"args": ["run", "dev"]`. The dev refers to a script in my package.json

In the console it says:
` *  Executing task: \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\jacob\alpaca-trader\bun run dev `
` *  The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\jacob\alpaca-trader\bun" does not exist. `

Sorry but I am still not getting what I need to do. Do you have any more hints for me @rioV8?

Comment: does `bun` exist if you use terminal to go to your Ubuntu VM. First make your last sentence in the question clear. Describe what you want to do? , What is `bun`? Do you work remote, or have you opened a remote workspace? Why do you have a `process` task? looking at the docs with process you have to specify the full path of the executable. Have you tried a `shell` task? This will type the command as given to the terminal

Comment: Indeed, it should be a shell task and not a process. To be completely honest, I did not know the difference until just now.

Now the task appears to run correctly because it executes the expected command. However, I am getting a different error now. I have updated both the question title and description to reflect this.

Bun is a new JavaScript runtime that I am trying out. Running `bun run` is equivalent to `node run`. Thank you for your help @rioV8.

Comment: you better ask a new question because this 24 hour question is not turning up on peoples feed so not a lot of people will see it.

Comment: note: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_tasks